# Matrix equation, simplified from $4\times 3$ to $3\times 3$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I am confused as to how this is simplified, The image shows the question and what the mark scheme says but I do not understand it.

[image: The question and markscheme answer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\left[ \begin{array}{c c}
A & v 
\end{array} \right]\cdot \left[ \begin{array}{c}
u \\
w
\end{array} \right]=Au+wv=p\Leftrightarrow Au=p-wv,$$
where
$$A=\left[ \begin{array}{c c c}
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 2 & 1\\ 
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array} \right],\quad
v=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\ 
1
\end{array} \right],\quad
u=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\ 
z
\end{array} \right], \quad
p=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\ 
0
\end{array} \right].$$